# Unable to connect WFS datasource with ogr, but works with QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr2ogr

I am accessing some WFS layers via QGIS. 
I want to download those same layers via ogr. This doesn't work and I can't find why.

The WFS URL is https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/wfs
The layer I want to acess from that WFS is "anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds"

In the windows command prompt, I put:
ogrinfo WFS:"https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds&srsName=EPSG:31370"

I get "unable to open datasource ... with the following drivers.

***I cannot understand why I can access this layer via QGIS, but not through ogr?*** Am I missing somehting?

PS 1
I am able to open WFS layers from other sources
PS 2
My GDAL version is 2.2.4

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work with this syntax

```
ogrinfo wfs:https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/wfs anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds

INFO: Open of `wfs:https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/wfs'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=Publieke Download Service van Mercator
  PROVIDER_NAME=Vlaamse Overheid - Beleidsdomein Omgeving - MercatorNet
  TITLE=Mercator Publieke Download Service

Layer name: anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=INSPIRE - beschermde gebieden - Vogelrichtlijngebieden
  KEYWORD_1=BESCHERMINGSZONES
  KEYWORD_10=SBZ-V_22072005
  KEYWORD_11=AGENTSCHAP VOOR NATUUR EN BOS
  KEYWORD_12=NATURA2000
  KEYWORD_13=NATURA 2000
  KEYWORD_14=RAADPLEEGDIENST
  KEYWORD_15=WMS
  KEYWORD_16=WEB MAP SERVICE (WMS)
  KEYWORD_17=Toegevoegd GDI-Vl
  KEYWORD_18=Vlaamse Open data
  KEYWORD_19=Metadata INSPIRE-conform
  KEYWORD_2=VOGELRICHTLIJNGEBIEDEN
  KEYWORD_20=Metadata GDI-Vl-conform
  KEYWORD_21=Lijst M&amp;R INSPIRE
  KEYWORD_22=Beschermde gebieden
  KEYWORD_3=VOGELRICHTLIJNGEBIED
  KEYWORD_4=VOGELSOORTEN
  KEYWORD_5=HABITATRICHTLIJN
  KEYWORD_6=VOGELRICHTLIJN
  KEYWORD_7=SBZ-V
  KEYWORD_8=LEEFGEBIEDEN
  KEYWORD_9=EUROPESE RICHTLIJN
  TITLE=Protected Sites - Birds
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 24
Extent: (3799756.790600, 3083976.313000) - (4029841.660200, 3161326.304800)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Europe Equal Area 2001",
        METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9820]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Europe - ETRS89"],
        BBOX[32.88,-16.1,84.17,40.18]],
    ID["EPSG",3035]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Geometry Column = geom
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
gml_identifier: String (0.0)
gml_description: String (0.0)
inspireid_identifier_localid: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds):1
  gml_id (String) = PS.ProtectedSite-birds.id1
  gml_identifier (String) = http://id.natuurenbos.be/vglrlid1
  gml_description (String) = BE2301134
  inspireid_identifier_localid (String) = id1
  MULTIPOLYGON (((3874154.4746 3149660.5224,3874110.9065 3149773.1917,3874090.6666 3149800.1456,3874072.0696 3149819.0542,3874052.6525 3149840.5202,3874031.8793 3149873.3491,3874008.4706 3149917.7042,3873982.4284 3149957.8568,3873940.9356 3150049
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate
 the "page" name from the parameters with a `?` instead of a `&`

```
ogrinfo -al -so "https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/wfs?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds&srsName=EPSG:31370"
ERROR 6: Update from remote service not supported
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `https://www.mercator.vlaanderen.be/raadpleegdienstenmercatorpubliek/wfs?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=anb_insp:PS.ProtectedSite-birds&srsName=EPSG:31370'
      using driver `GML' successful.

Layer name: PS.ProtectedSite-birds
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 24
Extent: (22279.645100, 159110.542100) - (252613.701400, 239052.669900)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = geom
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
gml_identifier: String (0.0)
gml_description: String (0.0)
inspireid_identifier_localid: String (0.0)
```